# My implementation of std::list gives a lot of errors

Tags: c++, list, templates, stl, linked-list

I have written my implemenetation of List template that works like std::list. This is a **List.h** file:

```
#include <memory>

template<typename T>
class List {

    class Node {
    public:
    T data;
    Node *previous;
    Node *next; //is that T needed?
    Node(T &d, Node *p, Node *n) : data(d), next(n) { };
    };

private:

    Node *head; //first element
    Node *tail;

    void create() { head = tail = NULL; }

    void create(const List &rhs);

    void uncreate();
public:
    typedef T *iterator;
    typedef const T *const_iterator;
    typedef size_t size_type;
    typedef T value_type;

    List() { create(); };

    List &operator=(const List &rhs);

    List(const List &rhs) { create(rhs); };

    ~List() { uncreate(); };

    T *begin() { return head->data; };

    T *end() { return tail->next->data; };

    T front() { return head->data; };

    T back() { return tail->data; };

    bool empty() {return head==NULL;}

    size_type size() { return tail - head + 1; }; //add one here?

    T &operator[](size_type i);

//    const T &operator[](size_type i) const; //how to implement and do not duplicate code?

    T *push_back(T &data);

    T *push_front(T &data);

    void pop_front();

    void pop_back();


};
```

This is my **List.cpp** file

```
#include "List.h"
#include <cassert>
#include <iterator>

template<typename T, class Node>
class iterator : public std::iterator<std::bidirectional_iterator_tag, Node*, Node&>{
    Node* underlying;

public:
    explicit iterator(Node *n):underlying(n){};
    iterator():underlying(nullptr){};

    iterator& operator++() { //preinc
    assert(underlying != nullptr && "Out-of-bounds iterator increment!");
    underlying = underlying->next;
    return *this;
    }

    iterator operator++(int) { //postinc
    assert(underlying != nullptr && "Out-of-bounds iterator increment!");
    iterator temp(*this);
    ++(*this);
    return temp;
    }

    iterator& operator--() { //predec
    assert(underlying != nullptr && "Out-of-bounds iterator decrement!");
    underlying = underlying->previous;
    return *this;
    }

    iterator operator--(int) { //postdec
    assert(underlying != nullptr && "Out-of-bounds iterator decrement!");
    iterator temp(*this);
    --(*this);
    return temp;
    }

    bool operator== (const iterator& rhs)
    {
    return underlying == rhs.underlying;

    }
    bool operator!= (const iterator& rhs)
    {
    return underlying != rhs.underlying;

    }
    T& operator*() {
    return underlying->data;
    }
};

void List::create(const List &rhs) {
    iterator this_iter = head;
    iterator rhs_iter = rhs.head;
    while(rhs_iter!=NULL){
    this_iter->data = (rhs_iter++)->data;
    ++this_iter;
    }
}

List::value_type &List::operator[](List::size_type i) {
    if (i < size() && i >= 0) {
    Node *temp = head;
    while (i > 0) {
        temp = temp->next;
        i--;
    }
    return temp->data;
    }
    throw std::out_of_range("Index out of range");
}

List &List::operator=(const List &rhs) {
    if (&rhs != this) {
    uncreate();
    create(rhs);
    }
    return *this;
}


List::value_type *List::push_back(List::value_type &data) {
    Node *n = new Node(data, tail, 0);
    tail->next = n;
    tail = tail->next;
    if(head==0) //if it was the first element added
    head = tail;
    return tail;
}

List::value_type *List::push_front(List::value_type &data) {
    Node *n = new Node(data, 0, head);
    head->previous = n;
    head = n;
    if(tail==0) //if it was the first element added
    tail = head;
    return head;
}


void List::pop_front() {
    Node* new_head = head->next;
    delete head->data; //delete, erase or what?
    head = new_head;
}

void List::pop_back() {
    delete tail->data; //delete, erase or what?
    tail = tail->previous;
}

void List::uncreate() {
    Node* temp = head;
    while(temp!=NULL){
    delete temp->data;
    temp = temp->next;
    }
    head = tail = NULL;
}
```

I have also created a simple main.cpp:

```
#include "List.h"
int main(){
    List<int> l;
    l.push_back(1);
    l.push_back(2);
    l.push_back(3);
}
```

but I have got a lot of errors:

```
    main.cpp:5:5: error: ‘l’ was not declared in this scope
         l.push_back(1);
         ^
    List.cpp:58:11: error: ‘T’ was not declared in this scope
     void List<T>::create(const List &rhs) {
           ^
    List.cpp:58:12: error: template argument 1 is invalid
     void List<T>::create(const List &rhs) {
            ^
    List.cpp:58:28: error: invalid use of template-name ‘List’ without an argument list
     void List<T>::create(const List &rhs) {
                            ^
    List.cpp: In function ‘void create(const int&)’:
    List.cpp:59:14: error: missing template arguments before ‘this_iter’
         iterator this_iter = head;
              ^
    List.cpp:60:14: error: missing template arguments before ‘rhs_iter’
         iterator rhs_iter = rhs.head;
              ^
    List.cpp:61:11: error: ‘rhs_iter’ was not declared in this scope
         while(rhs_iter!=NULL){
           ^
    List.cpp:62:9: error: ‘this_iter’ was not declared in this scope
         this_iter->data = (rhs_iter++)->data;
         ^
    List.cpp: At global scope:
    List.cpp:67:1: error: invalid use of template-name ‘List’ without an argument list
     List::value_type &List::operator[](List::size_type i) {
     ^
    List.cpp:79:1: error: invalid use of template-name ‘List’ without an argument list
     List &List::operator=(const List &rhs) {
     ^
    List.cpp:88:1: error: invalid use of template-name ‘List’ without an argument list
     List::value_type *List::push_back(List::value_type &data) {
     ^
    List.cpp:97:1: error: invalid use of template-name ‘List’ without an argument list
     List::value_type *List::push_front(List::value_type &data) {
     ^
    List.cpp:107:6: error: ‘template<class T> class List’ used without template parameters
     void List::pop_front() {
          ^
    List.cpp: In function ‘void pop_front()’:
    List.cpp:108:5: error: ‘Node’ was not declared in this scope
         Node* new_head = head->next;
         ^
    List.cpp:108:11: error: ‘new_head’ was not declared in this scope
         Node* new_head = head->next;
           ^
    List.cpp:108:22: error: ‘head’ was not declared in this scope
         Node* new_head = head->next;
                      ^
    List.cpp: At global scope:
    List.cpp:113:6: error: ‘template<class T> class List’ used without template parameters
     void List::pop_back() {
          ^
    List.cpp: In function ‘void pop_back()’:
    List.cpp:114:12: error: ‘tail’ was not declared in this scope
         delete tail->data; //delete, erase or what?
            ^
    List.cpp: At global scope:
    List.cpp:118:6: error: ‘template<class T> class List’ used without template parameters
     void List::uncreate() {
          ^
    List.cpp: In function ‘void uncreate()’:
    List.cpp:119:5: error: ‘Node’ was not declared in this scope
         Node* temp = head;
         ^
    List.cpp:119:11: error: ‘temp’ was not declared in this scope
         Node* temp = head;
           ^
    List.cpp:119:18: error: ‘head’ was not declared in this scope
         Node* temp = head;
                  ^
    List.cpp:124:12: error: ‘tail’ was not declared in this scope
         head = tail = NULL;
```

I know that my implementation will not work but I am not even able to check what is wrong because I cannot run it. Could anyone help me to fix it?

Comment: Error message (line 4) references a line of code different than the ones you posted

Comment: In your actual code do you have `List<int> l;` or `List l<int>;`?

Comment: Templates are always "hard to compile", so writing hundreds of lines and then trying to compile them is not the good strategy. Start trying to compile a shorter piece of code .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void List::create(const List &rhs) {
    ...
}
```

You have to add `template` to list definitions

```
template<typename T>
void List<T>::create(const List<T> &rhs) {
    ...
}
```

Here you have declared

```
T *push_back(T &data);
```

But it is later defined as

```
List::value_type *List::push_back(List::value_type &data) 
{
    ...
}
```

Easy way to fix it is to put declaration and definition together. So change `T *push_back(T &data);` to:

```
T *push_back(T &data)
{
    Node *n = new Node(data, tail, 0);
    tail->next = n;
    tail = tail->next;
    if (head == 0) //if it was the first element added
        head = tail;
    return tail;
}
```

---

---

Edit:

Even if this compiles it has many other errors and leaks. Below is a simplified version of `List`

Also it takes more work to define copy constructor and assignment operator. They have to copy the other list by using `List::push_back`. For the time being we make them inaccessible (by declaring them as private) so they won't be used by accident.

```
template<typename T>
class List
{
private:
    List &operator=(const List &rhs);
    List(const List &rhs);

public:
    class Node
    {
    public:
        T data;
        Node *prev, *next;
        Node(T dataT)
        {
            data = dataT;
            next = prev = NULL;
        };
    };
protected:
    Node *head, *tail;
public:
    Node *get_head() { return head; };
    Node *get_tail() { return tail; };

    List()
    {
        head = tail = NULL;
    };

    ~List()
    {
        while (head)
            remove(head);
    };

    //Node *push_back(T dataT) //use this for older compilers
    Node *push_back(const T &&dataT) //for C++ 14
    {
        Node *node = new Node(dataT);
        if (head == NULL)
        {
            //adding first item to list
            head = tail = node;
        }
        else
        {
            //adding item to end of the list
            node->prev = tail;
            tail->next = node;
            tail = node;
        }
        return node;
    }

    void remove(Node *node)
    {
        if (!node) return;
        if (node == tail && node == head)
        {
            //deleting the only node, nothing will be left
            head = tail = NULL;
        }
        else if (node == tail)
        {
            tail = node->prev;
            tail->next = NULL;
        }
        else if (node == head)
        {
            head = node->next;
            head->prev = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            //deleting a node in the mid
            node->prev->next = node->next;
            node->next->prev = node->prev;
        }
        delete node;
    }

    size_t size()
    {
        size_t i = 0;
        Node *node = head;
        while (node)
        {
            node = node->next;
            i++;
        }
        return i;
    }

    T &operator[](size_t i);
};
```

usage:

```
int main() 
{
    List<int> list;
    list.push_back(1);
    list.push_back(2);
    list.push_back(3);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
        std::cout << list[i] << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Still have got " invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘List<int>::value_type& {aka int&}’ from an rvalue of type ‘int’
     l.push_back(1);"

Comment: This declaration doesn't take constants: `T *push_back(T &data);` it should be changed to `push_back(T data)`, there are other issues. See updated answer.

Comment: So do I need  T *push_back(T &data); and  T *push_back(T data); or just only the second one?

Comment: The first method is pass by reference, it is more efficient. The second one is pass by value and is easier. For fundamental data types "pass by value" is just as efficient. So yes, use the second one. You can't use both, unless you change the function name for one of them. C++ 14 introduces a new feature, you can use `Node *push_back(const T &&dataT)` this will always pass by reference, and if you directly input fundamental variables it treats it as right-hand value. See update.

Comment: By the way, I made `head/tail` protected again and added function `get_head()` and `get_tail()` in case access is required to `head` and `tail`.